# Find which StoryBoard has been initialised in ViewController? Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

So I'm using Xcode to make an app... and instead of using size classes or auto layout to account for various iOS screen sizes, I do a screen height test in the `AppDelegate.m` and load a specific `Storyboard` based on what the screen height is returned as; that way, all `storyboards` can use the same `ViewController`.

My app does this successfully and loads one of four `Storyboards` based on the devices height which are then all controlled by the only `ViewController`.

My question is, is there a function that can return which `Storyboard` has been initialised/is in use? The reason being is I want to load different variable tolerances based on which `Storyboard` is in use.

I've had a search around and can't seem to find one and I've only found one resource (youtube) which even describes this method.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is there a function that can return which Storyboard has been initialised/is in use?

Every view controller has a `storyboard` property that points to the storyboard from which it was loaded. That probably won't help you, though -- storyboards don't have identifiers that you can retrieve, so just having a pointer to the storyboard won't let you differentiate between your storyboards.

> The reason being is I want to load different variable tolerances based on which Storyboard is in use.

One way to handle this is to store the information you need in the "user defined runtime attributes" for your view controller. You could store just an identifier, or you could store the "variable tolerances" directly. Let's say you just want to store an identifier. Add a property to your view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
//...
@property(nonatomic) NSString *storyboardID;
//...
@end
```

Next, set the value for key `storyboardID` in the user defined attributes for your view controller in each storyboard. Select your view controller in each storyboard and choose the Identity Inspector:

[image: identity inspector]

Done! Now you can read the value in your code:

```
if ([self.storyboardID isEqualToString:@"iPhone4Storyboard"]) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Nice. I didn't know that (obviously aha). Thanks for taking the time to post this. Definitely going try and implement this method. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting the storyboard at runtime you can just keep a variable from an enum in your app delegate that knows which version of the storyboard it is running. That way whenever you need to fork your code you just use a switch statement.

Comment: Thank you. I have just posted an answer below, which hopefully is what you were suggesting. Please comment if it is wrong or can be improved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Mr Bravo said above, this is what I implemented:

In `.h`:

```
    enum deviceTypes
        {
            iPhoneScreen35,
            iPhoneScreen4,
            iPhoneScreen47,
            iPhoneScreen55
        };

    typedef NSInteger devState;

    devState deviceInUse;
```

In `AppDelegate.m`, set **type** based on which `Storyboard` is used:

```
    deviceInUse = iPhoneScreen35;
```

In `.m`, set variables based on what **type** was set in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
   -(void)SetVariablesForDevice{

       if(deviceInUse == iPhoneScreen35){
              //stuff
       }
       if(deviceInUse == iPhoneScreen4){
              //stuff
       }
       if(deviceInUse == iPhoneScreen47){
              //stuff
       }
       if(deviceInUse == iPhoneScreen55){
              //stuff
       }

   }
```